# Vuejs router-view not displaying view when script tag is included

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router

so my vue is doing weird stuff and i cant figure it out or find a solution in internet.
so i use router to go to a different view, it works if i dont have a script tag included

```
<style lang="scss" src="../assets/scss/view/pokemonOverview.scss"></style>
<template>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit, nihil?
</template>
```

but when i add the script tag like this

```
<style lang="scss" src="../assets/scss/view/pokemonOverview.scss"></style>
<template>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugit, nihil?
</template>

<script>

</script>
```

it immediatly stops displaying the content on this page, in this case lorem ipsum. can someone explain to me what is going wrong when i add the scrip tag?

i already narrowed it down to the problem being the script tag, but i cant find anything that helps on the internet, and i am out of ideas to try to make it work

Thanks

Comment: You have inspect your console (inside browser inspector), and no error is print?

Comment: no errors nothing, but for some reason it works now, im so confused, it just fixed itself after hours of shitting around

Comment: You sur have somethings changed, maybe your process have failed building and after a reset is now works. But in every case, adding a script balise empty is not a problem and expect to works fine :)